# MySQL very slow on WAMP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wamp, wampserver

[image: Navigating to WordPress plugins page]

I've been having very slow PHP to MySQL connections for a while now. I'm 99% sure the issue is MySQL because when I run PHP that has no DB connection it's fast.

I'm running WAMP on Windows 7. I've tried just about all the other suggestions like disable iPV6 and use 127.0.0.1 for MySQL lookups instead of localhost. The screen shot shows that I'm waiting over 12 seconds for the server to respond. The green color from the Chrome console for that request is called Time to first byte: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing.

Has anyone come across this issue that has fixed it? It's killing my productivity!

Apache Version :
2.4.9

PHP Version :
5.5.12

MySQL Version :
5.6.17

Comment: Have you tried a basic bare-bones PHP script or tried using a MySQL client rather than testing with full-blown Wordpress?

Comment: Good observation Wesley. I just did that and pulled all 8000+ rows in the post_meta table. Time to first byte was 50ms. So it looks like a WordPress issue. But how do I begin to pick apart where the bottleneck is?

Comment: I'd start with a clean installation and no plugins. I don't know much about WP but there should be some logging/profiling abilities.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have noticed that if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` as the DB_HOST the database works faster.

This applied to any use of the host name for MySQL.

So try changing this parameter in your `wp-config.php`

From

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

To

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it make any difference?

Comment: How in the *explative* does that make it faster?! I've been fighting this for months. Connection very slow, debugging taking forever and it's because of a DNS lookup? localhost -> 127.0.0.1 fixed everything! Make's no sense!!!

But thank you. Wish I could give multiple upvotes for your simple answer.